# Passing Hidden value in anchor tag in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have the following anchor tag:

```
 <a href="<?php  echo base_url('admin/add_images'); ?>" class="btn green">Add New <i class="icon-plus"></i></a>
```

Here in base_url(admin/add_images), **admin** is name of controller, **add_images** is name of method in admin controller, I can do it in GET Method like base_url(admin/add_images?id=$id) however I am unable to pass it through POST method, to not shown it in url.

If you people have any idea or practice about it, then let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: anchor tag cannot pass hidden values. or use AJAX button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass "hidden" (it's not really hidden, but not visible for common users), you have two options:

1) change your `<a>` tag to `<button>` and put your hidden value inside hidden field.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php  echo base_url('admin/add_images'); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <button type="submit" class="btn green">Add New <i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
</form>
```

2) if possible, use session, store your hidden value inside [flashdata](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata).